# g++-4.2: No such file or directory on OSX 10.12.4

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, makefile, g++

I am trying to install a ruby gem - therubyracer and i get the following error -

```
make "DESTDIR="
compiling accessor.cc
make: /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

OSX 10.12.4
Xcode 8.3.2
I have installed the command line tools for xode

Comment: What is the output of `g++ -v`?

Comment: I have understood and solved this issue. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this issue. This is faced by people who upgrade directly from yosemite to sierra.

This caused as apple-gcc42 is cannot be installed due to incompatible upstream dependencies with sierra. However, gems like therubyracer have not been upgraded to support this. They look for g++ to be installed in /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42 directory. To fix this, manually add the directory and then create a soft link so that the bundle install of gems work -

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++ /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/g++-4.2
```